# Why is does my stopwatch keep reseting after 1 second

Tags: c#, stopwatch

So I have the following code block:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
while (sw.Elapsed.Seconds<10)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() + " ms");
}
sw.Stop();
```

and in the output I have

```
50 ms
101 ms
151 ms
202 ms
253 ms
304 ms
355 ms
405 ms
456 ms
507 ms
558 ms
608 ms
659 ms
710 ms
761 ms
812 ms
862 ms
913 ms
964 ms
15 ms
65 ms
116 ms
167 ms
218 ms
```

Why does it reset every 1000 ms?  I need to wait for 10 seconds and I can't use `Thread.Sleep(10000);` because this 3rd party library i use sleeps also and I need it to do stuff during that time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `Stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds` just outputs the milliseconds component of the elapsed time. It is **not** the total time in milliseconds. This is clear from the documentation. `Stopwatch.Elapsed` is an instance of `TimeSpan` and [`TimeSpan.Milliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.milliseconds.aspx) states:

> Gets the milliseconds component of the time interval represented by the current `TimeSpan` structure.

If you want the output in milliseconds, and you want the total milliseconds, then use [`TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx):

> Gets the value of the current `TimeSpan` structure expressed in whole and fractional milliseconds.

always, Always, ALWAYS check the documentation!

Answer (score 6):

you need the [`TotalMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) property of `sw.Elapsed`, instead of `sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds`

Answer (score 1):

You do not necessarily need to use the `TimeSpan` returned by the `Elapsed` property.

`StopWatch` exposes an `ElapsedMilliseconds` property directly that returns the total number of milliseconds as a `long`. Going through the `Elapsed` property to get `TotalMilliseconds` will yield a double. Use the value that makes most sense to you.